# arXiv: "x.pdf appears to have been produced by TeX"

Tags: pdf, arxiv

How does arXiv determine that a PDF has been produced by TeX?

E.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Most probably arXiv reads the source code of the PDF.
E.g. from a paper I have opened with Notepad++

```
<</Creator( TeX output 2011.03.09:1851)/Producer(MiKTeX-dvipdfmx \(20100328\))/CreationDate(D:20110309185222+01'00')>>
```

note:maybe you want to try to ask this in academia.stackexchange

Comment: Thanks, I tried emptying this tag but apparently Arxiv uses some detection algorithm a bit more advanced than simply reading the Creator tag.

Answer (score 2):

This blog post has a solution:
http://blog.coudert.name/post/2014/11/26/Author-produced-PDF-from-LaTeX-on-the-arXiv

For those looking for the quick fix, go to terminal and execute:

`sed -e '/PTEX\./s/./ /g' < submitted.pdf > arXiv.pdf`

If on OS X, run these first:

`export LC_CTYPE=C`

`export LANG=C`